# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined react rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I just fixed two errors like this.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`
`Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined`

Now I get this. I just keep getting these errors. I am just trying to implement react with rails for the first time and I am trying to say a simple "Hello React" from a react component through a html div class. I am not able to.

**application.js**

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require react
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="react"></div>
```

**main.jsx**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


let documentReady = () => {
    React.render(
        <h1>Hello React</h1>,
        document.getElementById('react')
    );  
};


$(documentReady);
```

Comment: what about start all over following this complete guide https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md

Comment: if this is not about the basic configuration maybe post it in the react section

Comment: Have you tried `//= require jquery //= require jquery_ujs //= require rails-ujs
//= require react
//= require_tree .`

The order matters and `rails_ujs` depends on `jquery`

Comment: @brandNew didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Move `require_tree .` at the end in `application.js` like:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require react
//= require_tree .
```