# Uncaught ReferenceError: controller is not defined in react js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

This is the second tutorial that I am following due to failure in versions and dependencies in the earlier. As you can guess I am just trying to get started with react here.

I created a controller called `Appointments`. This is my controller jsx inside the components folder.

**app/assets/js/components/appointments.jsx**

```
var Appointments = React.Component({
    render: function() {
        return (
         <h1>React calender</h1>
        )
    }
});
```

**appointments/index.html.erb**

```
<%= react_component 'Appointments' %>
```

And I restarted rails server. All I see is a blank browser and console showing this

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Appointments is not defined
```

Comment: have you tried `class Appointments extends React.Component`

Comment: @brandNew No I havent. Where should I add this ?

Comment: Instead of `var Appointments = React.Component`, try `class Appointments extends React.Component`

Comment: I just replaced that line like you said. Now I am getting a syntax error at  `});` in appointments.jsx. Saying `unexpected token`

Comment: I have posted an answer, have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you most probably meant to do is this

```
const Appointments = React.createClass({
    // ...
    render() {
    return <div>{this.state.hello}</div>;
  }
});
```

Which is not a very good thing if you plan to or have internal state and/or refs

It is recommended to rather do it like this

```
class Appointments extends React.Component {
   // ...
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.hello}</div>;
  }
}
```

So in your case your component should change from:

```
var Appointments = React.Component({
  render: function() {
    return (
     <h1>React calender</h1>
    )
  }
});
```

to this:

```
class Appointments extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <h1>React calender</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This is now displaying the h1 element. But now I am getting a console error like `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. I been getting this error in another tutorial that I was following. It would be really great if you tell me how to get rid of this. I have actually posted a question about that issue but wasnt able resolve anything.

Comment: May you please share the link to the question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627098/uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined-react-rails?noredirect=1#comment82214797_47627098